# Propel using a single query to get a result and change the order

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I've got a simple Propel query below which is to filter based on the country code (ordered alphabetically). However, I need to be able to do a filter to make a certain `countrycode` view at the top. Is this possibly using a single Propel query?

My Query (at present):

```
$query = CountryQuery::create()
    ->filterByCountrycode($countryCode)
    ->find();
```

Now that would only find the single item as my results only have one result per countrycode (no duplicates). However, I would have thought that the next step would to do another query and find all of the results and merge them together, however doing two queries seems counter-productive. Is there a better way of doing this?

Example:

If the country code is GB then the query above will output United Kingdom. However, the desired results will give the list of Countrys in alphabetic order, however the first item would be United Kingdom.

Comment: I would do this as a custom `findWithSpecialOrdering()` function in your `CountryQuery` object, since (at a guess) you're dealing with low number of rows (100 or so). In the custom finder, just call `find()` and then search the resulting `PropelCollection` for your special case. If you find it, remove it from the array and pop it onto the beginning. This is all done in memory, so should be fairly fast.

Comment: Alternatively you can add a `special_order` column to this table, which is `0` for special cases and `1` otherwise. You can then order on this field, and then order on the country name secondarily.

Comment: @halfer Yes thats quiet a good take on that. I don't think I thought outside of the box enough with regards to modifying the array before it was output by the model.
What is considered best practice? Adding a virtual column or modifying the result array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @halfer suggested, you can add a virtual column and order by it. Here is the query:

```
$countryCode = 'ru';
$countries = \CountryQuery::create()
    ->addAsColumn('order_field', "CASE WHEN code = '$countryCode' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
    ->select(array('Id', 'Name', 'Code'))
    ->orderBy('order_field', \Criteria::DESC)
    ->orderById(\Criteria::ASC)
    ->find();
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you for your input I will have a look and get back to you with regards to this method. However, is there a known way to prepare the statement, to avoid any possiblity of injection? or would propel handle this?

Comment: Ah, this is better than my idea - I was recommending array slicing. This does things in the database layer, which is probably slightly faster. Liam is right, the `$countryCode` here would be susceptible to SQL injection if it comes from user input - I'd just run an initial lookup on the country table, and if it is not there, don't add the `addAsColumn` clause.